# C++ ImGui Filter using vector<string>

Tags: c++, vector, filter

Hey So I am currently reading the filenames of all .txt files inside a folder and adding these to "`vector<string> TxtFiles`".

I want these filenames to be displayed inside a Filter so you can search for a filename.

Here is an example for the Filter in ImGui:

```
static ImGuiTextFilter filter;
filter.Draw();
const char* Filterlist[] =
{
    "1: Word1",
    "2: Word2",
    "3: Word3",
    "4: Word4",
    "5: Word5",
};

for (int i = 0; i < IM_ARRAYSIZE(Filterlist); i++)
    if (filter.PassFilter(Filterlist[i]))
        ImGui::Text("%s", Filterlist[i]);
```

This works very well using "const char*" and a predefined list.
But as I read the filenames at runtime and don't want to predefine them I use "`vector<string> TxtList`" to "`TxtList.push_back(TxtFileName);`"

I tried to just change the code above to that:

```
static ImGuiTextFilter filter;
filter.Draw();
for (int i = 0; i < IM_ARRAYSIZE(TxtList); i++)
    if (filter.PassFilter(TxtList[i]))
        ImGui::Text("%s", TxtList[i]);
```

But for "IM_ARRAYSIZE" it gives me the following Error message:

> "no operator '*' matches these operands, operand types are: *
> std::vector<std::string, std::allocatorstd::string>"

Also "TxtList[i]" behind the "filter.PassFilter(.." gives me an Error:

> no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char" exists

How do I change the code here that the Filter would work with the vector TxtList?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know, what does macros `IM_ARRAYSIZE` contains, but it is probably something like that: `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`, but as you have switched to vectors, you can use `vector.size()`.

In order to fix second broblem, you probably need to add `.c_str()` after `TxtList[i]`, in order to convert `std::string` to `const char*`

Comment: IM_ARRAYSIZE is from the official imgui repo in imgui.h and it is:
"#define IM_ARRAYSIZE(_ARR)          ((int)(sizeof(_ARR) / sizeof(*_ARR)))       // Size of a static C-style array. Don't use on pointers!"

Comment: Okay thank you, so the TxtList.size(); fixed the first error thank you. Do you know how I could fix the second one?

Comment: Yeah, ".size()", not ".length()", ".length()" is for strings, sorry about that.

Comment: .c_str() also fixed the second issue, thanks a lot <3